# Second prepared statement is not firing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, prepare

thanks for your time.

Below I have two prepared statements, query & query2;

con is the connection var

The first query is running perfectly and updating the database.

The second query is not updating anything, although it is not giving any error.

When I look at the second query that is logged after a "successful" run, the inserted variable is looking like an empty string. i.e. `RESTI`=''

Why is this happening? Is my code in the right order for the second query to run?

```
$row = 1;
$con=mysqli_connect("connect info");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL Error 1: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   //error reporting done here
}
else
{
    $con->autocommit(false);
    $query = $con->prepare("UPDATE table where `INDEX`=?");
    $query2 = $con->prepare("UPDATE table2 where (SELECT column from table where`RESTI`=?)");

    $query->bind_param('i', $row);
    $query2->bind_param('i', $row);

    if($query->execute() == false)
    {
        //Failed!
        /ERROR HANDLING
    }
    else
    {
       //SUCCESS            
    }

    if($query2->execute() == false)
    {
        //Failed!
        /ERROR HANDLING
    }
    else
    {
        //Success       
    }
    $con->commit();
    $query->close();
    $query->close();
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: so me, both queries make no sense - both don't update anything

Comment: How do you see the first query updating the db? Note also that you are not closing query2, but instead closing the first query twice. Is this exactly your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your update statement should be:

```
"UPDATE table SET column=<new value to set> WHERE INDEX=?"
"UPDATE table2 SET <col to update>= (SELECT column from table where`RESTI`=?) WHERE condition
```

Make sure RESTI is an unique field and the subquery would only return scalar value